# Is it possible to store a response header in the csv file along with other config in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Is it possible to store a response header in the csv file along with other sample result configurations in JMeter ?

Save Elapsed Time
Save Response Time

Answer (score 0):

There is [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property which allows you to add arbitrary JMeter Variables values to the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles)

For example this is how you can extract `ETag` header value from https://jmeter.apache.org page and save it into a JMeter Variable

[image]

See [JMeter Regular Expression Extractor: How to Extract Tokens and Session IDs to Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-regular-expressions-extractor) article for more information on the concept.

Once done you can add the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
sample_variables=ETag
```

or include the same into JMeter command line. Next time you run your JMeter test in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) you will see an extra column with the header value:

[image]